# python script for Comparing data from two tables from mysql and storing the results in excel

Tags: python

table1
here having more information based on condition fetching the data and developers will be passing the data table2
select * from INS where PROJ_NO>='7000-00'
table 2
Here needs to check all the data,it should not contain other data which is not mentioned in the condition,if contain has to show error like extra column has there and finally results will be stored in excel
select LOG_PROJ_NO from INNOTAS_PROJ_DTA_LOG(NOLOCK) 
based on proj_no needs to check

Comment: You should propose a way, and we correct it, We are not a "code on demand" site.  Possibly you should do this directly on SQL.

Comment: i done using joins but i need to validate the data